# Progress indicator keeps spinning in meteor terminal after "App running". What's it thinking about?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor app which I run in development using the `meteor` command.

It writes this to the console:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app. 
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

but then for quite a while after that, the little text spinner keeps going ( | / - \ , repeat) for about 30 seconds. What's it still doing?

I tried `meteor --verbose` but there's no extra output at the time in which I'm interested.

**Edit:** 
Not much to see, but FullStack asked for a screenshot so here it is:
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Added. Why did you need one?

Comment: Okay, I haven't seen that before. Does the app load in the browser?

Comment: Yes. It works fine. Seems to be fully functional even when the spinner's still going.